# Fill PDF Form From Local Database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdf, fdf

My goal is to create a way fill a PDF form from a database. I have an inventory of items that I want to track and would like to do so by outputting to an existing pdf form. I would like to use a database that can easily be edited by a gui like access (that is installed on the computers at work). I am on work computers and am not sure if I will be able to run an exe's on them(like trying to use java with iText).

That sums up my goals and issues. I am very new to programming and was thinking I could do this with a webpage and have the database and the pdf form all stored in the same file and use the webpage to make queries to fill the pdf form while using access to edit the database for the inventory.

It appears php would be the best way to do this but it looks like php requires a server to run its code. So I was thinking I could host the php code on a server and attempt to access a the database at work using the db's shared drive location. Since I am new to database I am not sure if that is possible or if I would need to have the database hosted on a server.

Does anyone have any recommendations on how I could accomplish this. I was thinking about just having it all server based but I signed up for 1and1 hosting to experiment with and its MySQL database cannot be accessed remotely. I guess this is not a big problem but it would require me to develop my own gui for db editing.

I am not necessarily looking for code examples, just big picture ideas on how to accomplish this.

Comment: Too broad for stackOverflow. Narrow down your problem to some key questions, then ask for help if you get stuck.